# BVPs: Can one get numerical solutions without specifying boundary conditions?

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

This might be a stupid question, but I'm curious if you can find physicallty expected boundaries without explicitly specifying them in numerical solutions. To explain what I mean, imagine a very boring reaction-diffusion equation in 1D (assuming steady state for now), something like $\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z^2}-2=0$. Let's say at $z = 0$, $P=1$ always and at some unknown boundary $z_{n}$, there's both no flux ($\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} = 0$) and zero concentration ($P(z_{n}) = 0$).

Even though we don't know the boundary, we can easily solve this equation analytically, $p(z) = z^2  -2z(z_{n}) + z_{n}^2 $. From this, you can explictly deduce that $z_{n}= 1$, and you get this kind of plot of the function.

[image]

Now, imagine we wanted to solve this numerically for whatever reason - every method I've seen says we have to pre-specify the boundary conditions, but what if we only knew the source ($z=0$) condition, but knew there was some $z_{n}$ which satisfied the problem? In principle I wonder if you could use a finite difference scheme to approximate the lapacian and explicitly calculate each step until you came to a space where $P(z)=0$ *without* pre-specifying it? Or is there formal reasons this wouldn't work? Apologies if this is an ignorant question, just one I'm curious about.

Answer (score 1):

Such variable length problems can be reduced to constant length problems by writing $y(s)=P(sT)$ where $s\in[0,1]$. Then you could formally add $T$ as another component of the state with derivative zero. Some BVP solvers have the facility to separately declare such constant parameters. But still each such parameter adds a slot in the boundary conditions.

So in your example, $y''(s)=T^2P''(sT)=2T^2$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=1$, $y(1)=y'(1)=0$.